# Why don't scientists believe Earth's surface water came up from the mantle?

Tags: planet, earth, planetary-formation, water, geology

I read, periodically, that there is more water trapped in the mantle than there is in the oceans - possibly a lot more.

If so, why don't any geologists believe that Earth's surface and near-surface waters were brought up via plate tectonics?

Why do they always claim it is a great mystery concerning the origins of Earth's oceans?

Comment: Ok, so how did get it into the mantle then...? Who is they? [citation needed]

Comment: "I read, periodically". Where do you read? Cite your sources.

Comment: Eg, [Dehydration melting at the top of the lower mantle](https://www.science.org/doi/abs/10.1126/science.1253358) Schmandt et al. combined seismological observations beneath North America with geodynamical modeling and high-pressure and -temperature melting experiments. They conclude that the mantle transition zone—410 to 660 km below Earth's surface—acts as a large reservoir of water.

Comment: If this was a question about how water arrived on the Earth, it would be an astronomy (astrophysics/cosmology) question. But it's not framed that way – instead, it's about a *geological* issue, which is off-topic here. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 6):

If the question is actually "why don't any geologists believe that Earth's surface and near-surface waters were brought up from *the Earth's interior*?", then the premise is false since many geologists do believe that is possible, e.g. see

- Earth Science SE post on ["Water on Mars and Earth"](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/13366/27775)
- Earth Science SE post on ["Ocean water coming from Mantle vs coming from meteorites"](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/14292/27775)
- Wikipedia's article on ["Origin of water on Earth"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_of_water_on_Earth)
- Science article on ["Earth may have kept its own water rather than getting it from asteroids"](https://www.science.org/content/article/earth-may-have-kept-its-own-water-rather-getting-it-asteroids).

If you are specifically referring to plate tectonics, then as discussed in ["Was Earth completely covered in Oceans prior to the onset of plate tectonics?"](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/22375/27775), the answer may depend on how "plate tectonics" is defined.  Earth scientists have [have done research related to the hypothesis](https://phys.org/news/2014-12-hints-ancient-earth-watergeologically.html) "that Earth was formed with entire oceans of water in its interior, and has been continuously supplying water to the surface via plate tectonics ever since".

There certainly exists a [deep water cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_water_cycle) exchanging water between the oceans and the mantle, so your question is just about what the starting conditions were: all the water in the mantle, all the water on the surface, or water in both.  We don't know the precise answer, but that doesn't make it a "great mystery", just an area of research.